# 128GB Flash drive ejected improperly, its name has disappeared and also all its content

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, file-recovery

I had on this 128GB flash drive about 25-30GB of stuff in it, a bit of everything (images, documents, mp3s and much more) and somehow today when inserted in my mac,   first it disconnected and then when I re-inserted the stick, it didn't eject properly..I took it out and when re-inserting it again,first thing I noticed was that its name (Untitled) wasn't showing any more and when clicking on it, it doesn't show ANYTHING at all in it..it appears that there isn't anything at all in it any longer..all my folders and files are not showing any more..nothing at all...and if I do a 'Get Info' of the disk, is says that it has a capacity of about 126GB and that 126GB (also) are available..have I lost EVERTHING? Can please anyone suggest what should I try to see all my files again? Thank you in advance to whoever can kindly offer any suggestion..!!!

Comment: Its very likely you have lost everything.  You should choose the file recovery software of your choice, see if anything can be recovered, the file recovery software finding files is your only hope.

Comment: Has the drive gone read-only? Sounds like filesystem corruption to me...